# How to use Entity DataSource with subquery in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using `RadGrid` in Telerik and I am trying to use entity `DataSource` in code behind.  Initially, the `RadGrid` loads fine when the page loads but I am having an issue when i try to filter the `RadGrid` values based on the `TextBox` input value. I am getting this error

> "PART_NUMBER' could not be resolved in the current scope or context.
>   Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required
>   schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly."

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        EntityDataSource1.CommandText = "DetailData";
    }        
}

 protected void FilterBtn_Click(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.ImageButtonClickEventArgs e)
 {
     string partNumber = PartNumberTB.Text;
     EntityDataSource1.CommandText = @"SELECT value p FROM DetailData as p
 where REFERENCE_NUM in (select distinct REFERENCE_NUM from DetailData
  where (DetailData.PART_NUMBER like  '" + partNumber + "%' or PART_NUMBER = ''))";          
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to call the `Rebind()` method of your `RadGrid`?

Comment: The issue seems to me and i could be wrong that Entity Datasource requires special syntax when using custom SQL in code behind so Rebind did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using aliases in your query and see if that helps.

```sql
SELECT value p FROM DetailData as p 
WHERE p.REFERENCE_NUM in (select distinct s.REFERENCE_NUM from DetailData as s
WHERE (p.PART_NUMBER like  '" + partNumber + "%' or s.PART_NUMBER = ''))
```

Here is a reference to [Subqueries with Aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190410(v=sql.105).aspx)

**Edit:**

You can test the query on [w3schools - SQL Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in) with the following code:

```sql
SELECT p.* FROM OrderDetails AS p
WHERE p.OrderID IN (SELECT DISTINCT s.OrderID FROM OrderDetails AS s 
WHERE (p.OrderDetailID LIKE '2%' OR s.OrderDetailID = 20))
```